# Clearing input after form submission in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have some confusion when clearing input after form submission. Code below.

**HTML :**

```
<form novalidate method="POST">
   <input ng-model="person.firstName" type="text" id="firstName" />
<button ng-click="edit(person)" name="saveBtn" >{{text}}</button>
```

**Controller :**

```
app.controller('PersonCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, personService) {

    $scope.init = function () {
       $scope.person = {};
    };

    $scope.edit = function (person) {
        personService.insertPerson(person.firstName);
        person.firstName = "";
    };

    $scope.init();
});
```

**Question:**
if I use `person.firstName = ""; OR $scope.person.firstName = "";` both have same behaviour and clear input fine. How it knows about person.firstName in html where I am not mentioning any scope**?**. Don't know if this is valid question but whenever I need to interact with html binding value than need to use $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because $scope.person and person points to the same object in your $scope.edit function (`$scope.person === person` is true).